# ASP.NET MVC+API and WCF with claims-based authorization and authentication against a custom DB and active directory

Tags: asp.net, wcf, authentication, claims-based-identity, identityserver3

We've are working on two (new) ASP.NET applications that use MVC/Razor views as a template engine to handle I18N/L10N (current culture is stored in, and retrieved from, a cookie on each request; Texts are loaded from resources).

Both applications consume the same WCF services through separate WebApis hosted in the same ASP.NET application as the MVC app. The APIs and are accessed by the web-based applications (HTML/JS).

Application **A** currently uses forms authentication (user credentials are validated by a WCF service against our application database), Application **B** uses windows authentication.

**TL;DR abstract:** We need to know stuff about the web-user down in the WCF services.

We need to:

- Have access to the current (web) user identity in the WCF services
- Transport verifiable information about that identity (e.g. role, group membership, ...) and use that information to restrict queries and operations (i.e. only allow to view and edit data in your own groups).
- Transparently authenticate users in application **B** (we do not want a separate login-screen or popup in IE)
- Support login through one time pads where authentication happened somewhat out-of-band (e.g. user gets an access-code which is only valid briefly, which authenticates him/herself as if he used his credentials to log in)
- Have brief session/token lifetimes, but use sliding expiration - user activity should extend his session/token lifetime. Inactive users should be logged out after short periods of inactivity.
- Have message security when communicating with the WCF services (ideally with certificates without having the actual authentication based on certificates due to the need for impersonation/delegation?)

My thoughts and impressions on this so far have been:

- Claims-based authorization would be nice to decouple the authorization from the business logic
- Claims-based authentication/authorization seems like it can transport all the information that we need to restrict the available data and operations (i.e. read group membership from claims)
- Token-based authentication is claims-based authentication (token is how claims are being transported)
- I need a security token service to authenticate the users (IdentityServer)
- Tokens could be somehow used during WCF channel creation to transport the current (claims) principal or corresponding token.
- I would have to use resource owner password credentials flow for our web-clients when migrating from forms to token-based authentication

So far I have:

- Set up IdentityServer with a single client using ROPC flow
- added OWIN to web application A and used `app.UseCookieAuthentication` and `app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication` to set up authentication but I'm not quite sure what exactly that entails so I'm not too comfortable with that for now.
- On Login (via MVC) I request an (access?) token from IdentityServer via `TokenClient.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync(username, password, scopes)`, try to build a `ClaimsIdentity` by accessing the userinfo? endpoint and set the cookie via `Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(id);`.
- A basic understanding on how token-based authentication and claims-based authorization works

What I don't have:

- Confidence that I fully understand how claim-based authorization works and can be implemented in WCF, MVC and WebApi
- Any idea what the different OWIN middlewares and extensions (`UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication`, `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` etc.) actually do, how and when they are supposed to be used and what security implications that has.
- Any idea what the `wS2007FederationHttpBinding` does and what it is used for, or what I have to configure in `Startup.cs` and what needs to be configured in the `web.config` or other places
- How to secure everything with proper certificates, SSL/HTTPS in such a way that I can both use it during development in our team as well as for deployment (we have config transformations in place per developer as well as for each build configuration)

Basically, I've read so much about WCF, WIF etc. that I have no clear idea what information is current, what the best practices would be and how I could implement something that would fit all our requirements.
The examples from IdentityServer didn't really help me much because, to me, they don't explain anything.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, even if you just help me get a better understanding of the terminology and technologies.

P.S.: We're running .NET 4.6

**Update:**
I've managed to get retrieve the token from IdentityServer and query the userinfo endpoint for the claims. Turns out I used `ClaimTypes.Email` etc. instead of `Constants.ClaimTypes.Email` - also only identity-scopes will yield claims on the userinfo endpoint, I had them specified on my resource scope.

My next step is trying to figure out how `UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication` prevents me from accessing anything and why it doesn't if I remove any required scopes...

**Update:** (2015-12-01)
I'm currently trying to somehow transfer the token to the WCF services transparently and have the current principal (or claims principal) available depending on the token. I don't have a clear way of achieving this yet.

The MVC and WebApi stuff seems to work fine now:

The MVC application is secured with the OWIN cookie middleware - on login where the forms authentication was used, I use a `TokenClient` and resource owner password credentials flow. I then query the `userinfo` (via `UserInfoClient`) and `introspection` (via `IntrospectionClient`) endpoints to build the claims, create a `ClaimsIdentity` and save that in the cookie. I also save the access token as a claim.

```
var id = new ClaimsIdentity(listOfClaims, "Cookies");
this.Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(id);
```

*Pitfall: the introspection endpoint requires to authenticate as the scope, not a client - which is slightly misleading in the samples, where the client and scope have the same name*

To validate the token on each request, I configure the `Provider` of the `CookieAuthenticationOptions` as a `new CookieAuthenticationProvider()` where I query the introspection-endpoint of IdentityServer during `OnValidateIdentity`:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
    LoginPath = new PathString("/User/Login"),
    LogoutPath = new PathString("/User/Logoff"),
    // setup more options etc..

    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = async context =>
        {
            // validate etc. - and if it fails call: context.RejectIdentity();
        }
    }
}
```

The WebApi is detached from the cookie authentication by extending the `Register(HttpConfiguration config)` which was used to set up the WebApi:

```
// prevent use of owin cookie auth
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();

// need bearer token auth
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
```

Additionally, I've set up `IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication` in the owin startup (basically, this is the only thing I do with the WebApi because I have several routes to several Apis and had trouble setting up multiple maps with dependency injection via Ninject...).

```
 app.Map(
    "/api",
    inner =>
    {
            inner.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(identityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions);
    });
```

Of course, that alone would only mean that the angular application would not be able to fetch any data - so on the single page application view I inject the token into the configuration as a constant and set the default headers by configuring the `$httpProvider`:

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  angular.module("myApp").constant("authorizationHeader", "Bearer @Model");
</script>
```

app:

```
myApp.config(["$httpProvider", "authorizationHeader", function ($httpProvider, authorizationHeader) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = authorizationHeader;
}]);
```

...so my only problem right now is pretty much how to transfer the token to the WCF service and how to set the claims identity from that token on the service (without having to do that explicitly - i.e. I don't want a separate parameter on my contracts)

P.S.: I can only configure the WCF service in the `app.config` because we're using self hosted WCF services and Ninject...

**Update** 2015-12-10
Succcess!

I transmit the reference token to the WCF service similar to how Dominick Baier suggests doing it: http://leastprivilege.com/2015/07/02/give-your-wcf-security-architecture-a-makeover-with-identityserver3/

Essentially this boils down to:

- Wrapping the reference token in a `Claim` in a new `ClaimsIdentity`
- Creating a new `SecurityTokenDescriptor` for that identity
- Wrapping with a `Saml2SecurityTokenHandler`
- Wrapping in a `GenericXmlSecurityToken`
- Creating the channel via `this.ChannelFactory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken(xmlToken);` (hint: cache the `ChannelFactory` but not the `Channel`)

This means that I had to change the bindings to `ws2007FederationHttpBinding`, change all urls to use `https` and ports in the `44300` to `44399` range for development on localhost (because Windows has preconfigured certificates and access control list for those ports - for deployment you have to add your certificate and allow the WCF-host-user to host an HTTP/SSL service there).
If any metadata endpoints are visible, then those must use HTTPS too (`binding="mexHttpsBinding"` and `<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />`)

In order to use that binding, the security has to be `TransportWithMessageCredentials`.

On the WCF-side, I removed all `SecurityTokenHandler` and added my own, which unwraps the reference token and uses the `introspection` endpoint from IdentityServer to build the identity (very similar to the example from IdentityServer).

That can be done in code or in the app.config (`ServiceCommunication` is the assembly where I keep all this stuff):

```
<configSections>
  <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
</configSections>
<system.identityModel>
<identityConfiguration name="identity">
  <securityTokenHandlers>
    <clear />
    <add type="ServiceCommunication.Authentication.IdentityServerWrappedReferenceTokenHandler, ServiceCommunication" />
  </securityTokenHandlers>
  <claimsAuthorizationManager type="ServiceCommunication.Authorization.ClaimsAuthorizationManager, ServiceCommunication"/>
</identityConfiguration>
```

For Authorization I define my own `ClaimsAuthorizationManager` which handles everything in the overridden `CheckAccess` method. Beware: that method gets called for each WCF contract method too.

The authorization can be on any plain code via `ClaimsPrincipalPermissionAttribute` or explicit via `ClaimsPrincipalPermission`. Doesn't even have to be WCF. Works out of the box in .NET 4.5

I use the `ClaimsPrincipalPermissionAttribute` as deep down as possible in my WCF services and additionally on the MVC/API controller actions.

Now I've got authentication of all users, prevent access to non-authenticated users (with redirect to login) and guarantee that only authorized users can access specific methods. :)

Comment: ...so I was editing that for so long that I ended up being logged out. I'm now stuck at the WCF part - the MVC and API works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've finally solved all this:

- I use IdentityServer3 for authentication and management of all the claims
- `app.UseCookieAuthentication` with my own `CookieAuthenticationProvider` to verify the reference token in MVC and to handle login like the previous forms authentication
- `app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication` for the API (each http request must have set a header `Authorize` with value `Bearer your-token-here`, most JS frameworks allow you to set that globally). Authentication is against IdentityServer, I've configured ClientId and ClientSecret (which are actually the ScopeId and ScopeSecret) so that it uses the introspection-endpoint. **Beware**: you'll only get claims for that specific scope, not for other scopes.
- Various `IdentityModel` clients to authenticate and validate (and fetch claims from userinfo and introspection endpoints)
- Wrapped reference or jwt token via `Ws2007FederationHttpBinding` and `TransportWithMessageCredentials` security
- My own `SecurityTokenHandler` on the WCF services to unwrap that token and validate it (and set identity/principal)
- My own `ClaimsAuthorizationManager` to authorize via `ClaimsPrincipalPermission`(`Attribute`)

Answer (score 0):

New internet security protocols like OAuth2 and OpenID Connect, don't play well with WCF SOAP services.

The authorization server issues JWT tokens when using the OAuth2 and OpenID Connect protocols. However, your SOAP WCF service(s) expect a SAML token in the envelope header when you use the `WS2007FederationHttpBinding`. [IndentityServer does not issue SAML tokens](http://leastprivilege.com/2015/01/25/identityserver3-1-0-0/).

While it's possible to issue and sign your own SAML tokens using the claims from the JWT token, it may be easier to replace the WCF SOAP services with a REST based services that expects a JWT token in the `Authorization` header.

I'm not sure why you'd want to use the resource owner password credentials flow. You may want to look into [using IdentityServer with an existing database](http://brockallen.com/2013/02/03/integrating-thinktecture-identityserver-database-with-an-existing-database/) and use the auth code flow instead.

P.S. Both [IdentityServer](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3) and [Katana](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/) (Microsoft's OWIN implementation) are open source, so you can figure out what all this code is actually doing.

Comment: Thanks for the info regarding JWT and SAML. I want to use ROPCF because we have multiple users and we need to scope the data to each user. As far as I understand it, the authorization code flow would be more something for internal server-to-server communication as the client would authenticate itself via its own secret. In this scenario we have only one or two clients but potentially hundreds of users.

Comment: No, in auth code flow, both the client and the user are authenticated (although client authentication is not required per se). The resource owner password credential is used in situations where you do not have a browser-like agent involved (as auth code and implicit flow are redirection based). Only in client credentials flow there is no user authentication.

Comment: I don't see user authentication in the auth code flow. Also, since I would use the access token (and refresh token) for each browser-initiated request (stored in cookie), getting the auth code first would be useless since I only need the token and don't need long lived access for non-user operations. My source for the flows is https://github.com/IdentityServer/Documentation/issues/73

Comment: The auth code flow redirects your browser to the authorization server, where the user logs in. It sends back an auth code via the browser to the client application which uses it to get an access token. This way the access token is never exposed to the browser and can therefore not be stolen. The real source for OAuth2 is https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749

Comment: Okay. Since we're migrating from Forms Authentication and we need proper localization and corporate design/UX for login etc., we're very hesitant to use any redirection based approach for now.

Comment: I should, in theory, be able to wrap the jwt token and use it with `ChannelFactory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken` but I'm stuck with how to handle that on the service - especially since I've got a reference token only... (the only example I could find was http://leastprivilege.com/2015/07/02/give-your-wcf-security-architecture-a-makeover-with-identityserver3/). I can't configure it in code though due to Ninject self hosted WCF service...